# In how many ways can $3$ kids divide $12$ oranges, the oranges all being of different sizes?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> In how many ways can $3$ kids divide $12$ oranges, the oranges all being of different sizes?

For some reason, I have a very hard time with these problems. I know that we can get the answer from the multinomial theorem
$$\binom{12}{4,4,4}$$
which can be thought of as placing $12$ distinguishable balls into $3$ distinguishable boxes. Why is this not equivalent to saying for each orange we can assign it to any of the $3$ kids so we get
$$3^{12}$$

I must be double counting a lot of situations in the second answer.

Comment: Are all oranges identical or distinct?

Comment: In the second answer, you are treating the oranges as unique objects.

Comment: Also, you're not given that you have to equally divide them, are you? That's what you're doing in the former.

Comment: oranges are different

Comment: here is the exact question : In how many ways can 3 kids divide 12 oranges, the oranges all being of different sizes

Comment: Is their answer just wrong?

Comment: In second case you are counting cases like the three get (1,1,1) oranges or they get (12,12,12) oranges.

Comment: @samjoe Not exactly I am creating sets of 12 with each value taking on values from 1 to 3

Comment: Oh I understand!

Comment: @parthkohli good point, the question doesn't mention that, but they give the multinomial answer

Answer (score 3):

If the oranges and kids are distinguishable, you are correct that there are $3^{12}=531441$ ways to distribute them as each orange can be given to any of the three kids.  Your $\binom{12}{4,4,4}=34650$ requires that each kid get four oranges, but that is not specified in the problem.

Comment: I think this is why I get so confused, is that many answers in online practice problems are wrong

Answer (score 0):

If the oranges are considered unique you have to  do 12P3  else if they are not unique and are all considered just identical oranges you have to do 12C3 that is the same as locating positions for 1s or 0s in a bitstring of size n 1s and 0s are identical so we say  choose k ( the number of positions we need to fill ) from n thats nCk

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect the exact statement of the problem, which was hidden in the comments.  You answered a different question than the intended one.